# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'. On deleting table cell app is crashing

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, tabs

I have a view controller which needs to delete a table view cell but when I run the app it crashes and gives this error.

**'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (5), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'**

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 95
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! PizzaListTableViewCell
        cell.commonInit(_imageName: "pizza_(indexPath.item)", title:name[indexPath.item], text: miscellaneousText[indexPath.item], amount: amount[indexPath.item])
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = DetailsVC() 
        vc.commonInit("pizza_(indexPath.item)", title:name[indexPath.item],text: miscellaneousText[indexPath.item], amount: amount[indexPath.item])
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle,    forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            self.Pizza1.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    }
```

Comment: When I see `Pizza1`, I'm afraid to see `Pizza2` somewhere else. What's the code of numberOfRowsInSection?

Comment: Update the dataset.  And refresh the table view.

Comment: There is only one entity(Pizza1)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return name.count
    }

Comment: Why does it return `name.count` when it should return `Pizza1.count`? As I guess you use `Pizza1` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Also, what's `name`? I guess you should use only ONE array for all.

Comment: @ThrinathSirna please share `tableview` all methods code which you used.

Comment: @RB's
  
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return  95
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! PizzaListTableViewCell
        cell.commonInit(_imageName: "pizza_\(indexPath.item)", title:name[indexPath.item], text: miscellaneousText[indexPath.item], amount: amount[indexPath.item])
        return cell
    }

Comment: @RB's
func  tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = DetailsVC()
        vc.commonInit("pizza_\(indexPath.item)", title:name[indexPath.item],text: miscellaneousText[indexPath.item], amount: amount[indexPath.item])
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the additional code, don't add it as comments

Comment: Using multiple, associated arrays is a bad idea; you will need to ensure you delete the relevant element from all arrays.  A much better approach is to have a single array of a struct that has the relevant properties.